# using column validation to set a column as mandatory

Tags: survey

I created Survey with with some service evaluation using radio button (Excellent,Very Good, Good, Fair, and poor)

each question is followed by a justification question

what we need is:

1- if the user answer the question with Poor or fair selection, the the next justification question  to be mandatory

2- any other selection, then the next justification to be an optional.

i tried to add some formulas in the question validations, but i always get the msg the the formula cant refer to another question.

many thanks for your help

Comment: it is because in column validation you are able to use only column of your interest, not other columns. What you need is Pre-Save action, example is SPServices PreSave action, more info can be found here: http://sympmarc.com/tag/presaveaction/

Comment: Dear, Thank you, but it is not what i want i think

Comment: I mean what i want simply to make the justification coulmn is mandatory or optional depending on the radio buttun selection from the previous column

Comment: yes, and you cannot do it in simple OOTB column validation as you proposed in your question.